# Industrial Phone Number Regex (a Regex problem)

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to extract phone numbers from messages submitted to me via a contact form. This "contact form" gets over a thousand submissions a day, and a lot of these submitters are making formatting mistakes, such as:

"Please call me back at925-943-2343 ext. 304" (no space before number)

Currently, my regex, which is below, is missing these numbers with certain formatting errors (such as the lack of space before the number)

```
foreach (...)
{
    $regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/'; 
    if (preg_match($regex, $msg))
    {
        $phonenumber = preg_replace($regex, '($1) $2-$3 ext. $4', $msg); 
        echo $phonenumber;
    }
}
```

Any tips?

**Related issue:**

```
$regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})' 
    .'(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})' 
    .'[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/'; 
$line = "(732) 912 0159 ";
if (preg_match($regex, $line))
{
    $phonenumber = preg_replace($regex, '($1) $2-$3 ext. $4', $line); 
    echo $phonenumber;
}
```

Why does this return nothing?

Comment: Do you have access to modify the contact form? If so, adding a phone number text box would be a lot more robust than trying to find a perfect regex.

Comment: Add a phone number input field on the form that has a format mask like http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. It would have to validate the format server side too. I know that's not the answer your looking for but it addresses the root cause of the problem (e.g. extracting phone numbers) rather than patching the symptoms.

Comment: I agree, usability-wise for you and the user the best solution seems to be to make a telephone # field for the users to input in.

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

Comment: Don't use regex to parse the number. Just remove the non-digit characters and split it into chunks of digits.

Comment: I do not have access to the contact form. Just the back-end. Bureaucracy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[01]?[- .]?\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}(?:i.{0,3}x?.{0,9})(\d{1,5})
```

Comment: $line = "Please call me back at925-943-2343 ext. 304"; if (preg_match($regex, $line)) { echo preg_replace($regex, '($1) $2-$3 ext. $4', $line); } outputs nothing, I'm afraid (with your regex).

Comment: Even just modifying it such that it will accept numbers with out a preceding space would be extremely beneficial, I think.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that I had the `^` at the beginning.  Having this character limits you to the beginning of a line when matching.